# Gulp/Foundation 6 'foundation watch' error

Tags: cmd, gulp, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Opening the command prompt in the folder I am working in. running 'foundation watch' and it gives me this error:

> [10:19:50] 'build' errored after 13 s
>   [10:19:50] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
>   Message:
>       An error occured in task 'clean'.
>   Error: foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
>   Exit status 1
>       at EventEmitter. (C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:214:16)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\Dev3\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

Comment: Can you post your gulpfile? Or at least the watch part. It's impossible to understand where the problem is for these details.